# How to control Keithley 2230 with Ubuntu PC host?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visa

I want to control a Keithley 2230 with an Ubuntu PC.

But I get a compilation error for the command is `gcc 2230.c -o 2230 -lvisa`:

```
/tmp/ccbIYaRH.o: In function `main':
2230.c:(.text+0x289): undefined reference to `viScanf'
2230.c:(.text+0x2f5): undefined reference to `viScanf'
/tmp/ccbIYaRH.o: In function `SendSCPI':
2230.c:(.text+0x47c): undefined reference to `viBufRead'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I check the file `visa.h`, and there are these two functions `viScanf` and `viBufRead`, but they are not in `libvisa.a` or `libvisa.so` according to the `nm` command.

What is the cause of this problem? How can I control a Keithley 2230 with an Ubuntu system?

**update:**
 I change viScanf and viBufRead to viRead, and after that can compile pass. click here for code:[mycode_link](https://gitee.com/zewen/codes/fxgp1c98wvo7lmrbkiajy32) , but in openPort() function, i can not find resource, mean after this line:

```
ErrorStatus = viFindRsrc(defaultRM, "?*", &fList, &numInstrs, desc);
```

numInstrs is 0, do you have any idear for this issue? thanks!

Comment: Where does the source code come from (including `libvisa` and the header file)? Can you link to an on-line copy of the source, or include it in your question?

Comment: Apparently the same issue, unanswered: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/librevisa/+question/237996

Comment: And your own program ...?

Comment: @tripleee you can install visa lib with this command: sudo apt install libvisa-dev, after that you will found libvisa at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvisa.so and visa.h at /usr/include/visa.h

Comment: here is my code, but only for debug,  I change viScanf and viBufRead to viRead, and after that can compile pass. click here for code:[mycode_link](https://gitee.com/zewen/codes/fxgp1c98wvo7lmrbkiajy32) ,  but in openPort() function, i can not find resource, mean after this line: ErrorStatus = viFindRsrc(defaultRM, "?*", &fList, &numInstrs, desc); numInstrs is 0,  do you have any idear for this issue? thanks!